# hibernate @DiscriminatorValue does not apply to associations

Tags: hibernate, annotations, associations, hibernate-annotations

I have the following inheritance hierarchy.

```
@Entity
@Table(FRUIT)
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColum(name="FRUIT_TYPE",discriminatorType=STRING)
public class Fruit {
..
@Id
private FruitId id;
...
}

@DiscriminatorValue("APPLE")
public class Apple extends Fruit {
...
@ManyToOne
private FruitBowl bowl; //this association is only present in the subclass

...
}

class FruitBowl .. {
...
        @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "bowl")
    @IndexColumn(name="POSITION",base = 1) 
        List<Apple> apples;
...
```

When I do a `session.load(Apple.class,...)`, it adds `FRUIT_TYPE = 'APPLE'` to the select query. But if I do a select on FruitBowl(which has a 1:m relationship with Apple), the select query on the Apple does not contain `FRUIT_TYPE = 'APPLE'`. Why does this happen? How do I rectify the problem?

Query
 --Query for FruitBowl

```
select fruitbowl0_.BOWL_ID as BOWL1_1_0_ from FRUITBOWL fruitbowl0_ where fruitbowl0_.BOWL_ID=?
```

--Query for Fruit to retrieve Apples (records with fruit_type ='A') 
--but it does not include that condition

```
select apples0_.ENTITY_ID as ENTITY3_1_, apples0_.POS as POS1_, apples0_.POS as POS0_0_, apples0_.ENTITY_ID as ENTITY3_0_0_, apples0_.COLOR as COLOR0_0_ from FRUIT apples0_ where apples0_.ENTITY_ID=?
```

Comment: @kan - I've edited my answer based on the query / data you've posted; please take a look.

Answer (score 4):

You can add `@DiscriminatorOptions(force=true)` to your "Fruit" class which will force hibernate to use the descriminator when querying this relationship.

This seems like something you would expect by default, but maybe there is some performance reason why it is not so.

Comment: Because generally speaking the discriminator is not part of the index.  So adding it to the WHERE-clause would indeed result in a slower query.  And, its not a valid mapping really from a Hibernate perspective given the data he presents.

Answer (score 0):

(Edited based on mappings / SQL queries / sample data posted in question / comments).

Your mapping specifies that `FruitBowl` contains a collection of `Apple`s. Hibernate will therefore not add discriminator value condition to loader query for that collection because it knows in advance that only `Apple` instances can be returned.

SQL queries you've posted do exactly that - load `FruitBowl` by id and subsequently load `apples` collection for that `FruitBowl` instance. The problem lies with the data you've posted:

```
 fruit_type entity_id  pos  color
     A         1        1   white
     B         1        2   blue
```

There's another instance of `Fruit` with discriminator value `B` - `Banana`? :-) - that has the same `entity_id` and thus is retrieved as part of collection loading query. The question here is - how was it inserted in the first place? There are two possible scenarios:

1. `Banana` is a subclass of `Apple`. In that case everything is correct, it should be returned as part of `apples` collection.
2. You've inserted the above data manually for testing purposes. This data is illegal from the Hibernate's standpoint - it would have **NEVER** be inserted by the Hibernate itself; this in turn leads to the behavior you're seeing. You need to either get rid of `Banana` row or remove its `entity_id` (thus removing it from `apples` collection).

Generally speaking, mixing object hierarchy and collection elements in the same table is not a good idea. Consider either re-mapping the hierarchy as "table-per-subclass" or mapping `apples` collection using `@JoinTable` - note that it will become uni-directional in the latter case.

Comment: The declaration is based on Apple rather than Fruit (just like you mentioned). But I do not see the FRUIT_TYPE = 'APPLE' in the select query.
Edited the original post to include FruitBowl class.

Comment: Can you post your query as well? In some cases, for example when you're loading a specific `FruitBowl` instance(s), its collection **cannot** contain anything other than `Apple`s by definition, so there's no reason to apply discriminator value condition.

Comment: Updated original post with the generated SQL. The FRUIT table had the following records. The query should have picked up only the first record. But it picks up both. So I think the where clause fruit_type = 'A' is needed even while fetching records for the association. Kindly give your feedback.
fruit_type  entity_id pos color
A              1       1  white
B              1       2  blue